# Second file upload one is not uploaded in to other directory

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Currently, I have two file upload ones and both only accept images. The process is that I made the upload to the another directory.  But, the problem is is only the first one got uploaded to another directory and the second picture is not uploaded. May I know how can I fix it?

Below is HTML codes.

```
<div id="fileone" style="display:block;">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="pnl" >Overall visual defect photo Wafer ID :</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -6px;">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="fileToUpload1" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" style="margin-top: 24px;" value="<?php echo $seal_qty; ?>">
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10"></div></div>

      <br>
      
      <br>
      <div id="filetwo" style="display:block;">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="pnl">Localized defect photo :</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -6px;">
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload2" id="fileToUpload2" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" style="margin-top: 5px;" value="<?php echo $seal_qty; ?>">
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10"></div></div>
```

```
var tomatch = /^[A-Za-z]{1}:([A-Za-z0-9_\-\\\ ]*)\\([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)[.](\w+)$/;
var barvalue = document.translot.fileToUpload1.value;
var barvaluetwo = document.translot.fileToUpload2.value;
    //alert(barvalue);

if (tomatch.test(barvalue))
{
    SynReqData(reqHttp2,'vdefectreport_result.php?refno=' + refno + '&probdect=' + probdect +'&rptdby=' + rptdby + '&lnum=' + lnum + '&device=' + device + '&pnl=' + pnl + '&dept=' + dept + '&lblwafer=' + lblwafer+ '&wfcrack=' + wfcrack + '&site=' + site + '&affectedwf=' + affectedwf + '&dectprocess=' + dectprocess +'&affctarea=' + affctarea + '&ptype=' + ptype + '&pk=' + pk + '&pkdmg=' + pkdmg + '&canis=' + canis + '&celidst=' + celidst + '&psyqty=' + psyqty + '&labelwafertxt=' + labelwafertxt + '&values=' + values + '&wfqty=' + wfqty + '&barvalue=' + barvalue + '&fileToUpload2=' + fileToUpload2+ '&fileToUpload3=' + fileToUpload3+ '&fileToUpload4=' + fileToUpload4 + '&othtxt=' + othtxt);
    return true;
}
else if (tomatch.test(barvaluetwo))
{
    SynReqData(reqHttp2,'vdefectreport_result.php?refno=' + refno + '&probdect=' + probdect +'&rptdby=' + rptdby + '&lnum=' + lnum + '&device=' + device + '&pnl=' + pnl + '&dept=' + dept + '&lblwafer=' + lblwafer+ '&wfcrack=' + wfcrack + '&site=' + site + '&affectedwf=' + affectedwf + '&dectprocess=' + dectprocess +'&affctarea=' + affctarea + '&ptype=' + ptype + '&pk=' + pk + '&pkdmg=' + pkdmg + '&canis=' + canis + '&celidst=' + celidst + '&psyqty=' + psyqty + '&labelwafertxt=' + labelwafertxt + '&values=' + values + '&wfqty=' + wfqty + '&barvalue=' + barvalue + '&fileToUpload2=' + fileToUpload2+ '&fileToUpload3=' + fileToUpload3+ '&fileToUpload4=' + fileToUpload4 + '&othtxt=' + othtxt);
    return true;
}
else
{
    alert('Invalid file name : ' +barvalue+ '\nNo special character allow in file name or path\ne.g \~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\+\=\{\}\[\]\|\;\\\'\,\"\<\>\?space');

}
```

Below here will be php and Javascript codes that I has been written.

```
$file = isset($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])? $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] : "";
$file_size = isset($_FILES["file"]["size"])? $_FILES["file"]["size"] : "";
$file_name = isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])? $_FILES["file"]["name"] : "";
                                
$filetwo = isset($_FILES["fileToUpload2"]["tmp_name"])? $_FILES["fileToUpload2"]["tmp_name"] : "";
$file_sizetwo = isset($_FILES["fileToUpload2"]["size"])? $_FILES["fileToUpload2"]["size"] : "";
$file_nametwo = isset($_FILES["fileToUpload2"]["name"])? $_FILES["fileToUpload2"]["name"] : "";
    
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $dataDir = "//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ews/web/webspool/temp/visualdefectreport/";
       
    if ($file_size <= 0 || $file_sizetwo <= 0 )
    {
        echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
        echo "  alert('No picture attached!')";
        
        echo "</script>";
    }
    else
    {     
        if(stristr($file_name, ".png")){
            $connection = mysqli_connect($apews_db_apews2, $apews_db_usr, $apews_db_pwd) or die ("Unableeeee to connect!");
            $dest = $dataDir.$file_name;

            if(move_uploaded_file($file,$dest))
            {
                echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
            echo "  alert('Visual Defect Report and pictures are successfully submitted!')";
          echo "</script>";
            }
        }
        else if(stristr($file_nametwo, ".png")){
            $connection = mysqli_connect($apews_db_apews2, $apews_db_usr, $apews_db_pwd) or die ("Unableeeee to connect!");
            $dest = $dataDir.$file_nametwo;

            if(move_uploaded_file($filetwo,$dest))
            {
                echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
            echo "  alert('Visual Defect Report and pictures are successfully submitted!')";
          echo "</script>";
            }
        }
        else if(stristr($file_name, ".jpg")){
            $connection = mysqli_connect($apews_db_apews2, $apews_db_usr, $apews_db_pwd) or die ("Unableeeee to connect!");
            $dest = $dataDir.$file_name;

            if(move_uploaded_file($file,$dest))
            {
                echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
                    echo "  alert('Pictures successfully uploaded!')";
                  echo "</script>";
            }
        }
        else if(stristr($file_nametwo, ".jpg")){
            $connection = mysqli_connect($apews_db_apews2, $apews_db_usr, $apews_db_pwd) or die ("Unableeeee to connect!");
            $dest = $dataDir.$file_nametwo;

            if(move_uploaded_file($filetwo,$dest))
            {
                echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
                echo "  alert('Pictures successfully uploaded!')";
                
            }
        }
        else if(stristr($file_name, ".jpeg")){
            $connection = mysqli_connect($apews_db_apews2, $apews_db_usr, $apews_db_pwd) or die ("Unableeeee to connect!");
            $dest = $dataDir.$file_name;

            if(move_uploaded_file($file,$dest))
            {
                echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
            echo "  alert('Pictures successfully uploaded!')";
          echo "</script>";
            }
        }
        else if(stristr($file_nametwo, ".jpeg")){
            $connection = mysqli_connect($apews_db_apews2, $apews_db_usr, $apews_db_pwd) or die ("Unableeeee to connect!");
            $dest = $dataDir.$file_nametwo;

            if(move_uploaded_file($filetwo,$dest))
            {
                echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
            echo "  alert('Pictures successfully uploaded!')";
          echo "</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
    
//X:\web\webspool\temp\visualdefectreport
    

  $file_name = "//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ews/web/webspool/temp/visualdefectreport/" . $file_name;
  $file_nametwo = "//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ews/web/webspool/temp/visualdefectreport/" . $file_nametwo;
```

Comment: ___NOTE___ The `<Input type="file" ..` does not have a `value` attribute so `value="<?php echo $seal_qty; ?>"` at best will be ignored and at worst may cause issues

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just removed em.

Comment: _Big Suggestion_ Create ONE connection to the database at the beginning of the script and use it all the way through the script.

Comment: You are using an `IF .. ELSE IF .. ELSE IF` structure. So once the first file is found, NO OTHER CODE in those else if's will get run

Comment: _Also_ If you look closely, none of those `else if`  are really needed. You do nothing differently based on the extention, which is what you are testing for within each of the `elseif`

Comment: You also do not appear to actually do anything with the database other than open a connection to it ??

Comment: Not sure its necessary now, but in future if you are going to show us code that uses a function you wrote, like `SynReqData()` its also quite relevant for us to expect to see that functions code :)

Comment: so how can I write for filetoupload2 if i wont use the if else if condition? @RiggsFolly

Comment: `SynReqData()` is unnecessary. I made that for keep other data into phpmyadmin.

Comment: ___Terminology___ phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP, it is not a DBMS. The DBMS is likely MySQL or maybe mariaDB. Like I said, not necessary this time as the bugs are obvious and elsewhere

Comment: You only need 2 IF's `if (fileone exists) { move file1 } if (filetwo exists) { move file 2 }` or maybe 4 ifs as you appear to be passing 4 file elements to the `SynReqData()` function

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you please show me in my codes? I'm only 3 weeks into this field and still quite confusing.

Comment: You are also using `IF ELSEIF` in that javascript, so it the first file is found you wont run the ELSEIF. _Something to think about_ In my 40 odd years in development using various languages on various hardware I cannot remember using an `IF ELSEIF` more than once or twice. I seriously think you should research how that structure actually works

Comment: Have a closer look yourself. There is an old addage in development K.I.S.S it stands for "Keep It Simple Squire" I changed the last word so as not to offend the sensitive :) But its a good addage. If your code looks like its getting overly complex, you probably ought to look at it again. Code almost never NEEDS to be complex.